# Match opposite of regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a quick question about Regular Expressions.

Can I specify a pattern and have everything else that doesnt fit the pattern to be matched?

For example, anything that does not fit into this pattern: `HT\d{4}`, I want to consider a match.

Answer (score 6):

yes, you can do this:  `(?!HT\d{4})`

It's called a "negative lookahead".  It is supported in most regex engines.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like `^.*$(?<!HT\d{4})`

But in most languages, you can use the original regex and use a logical `!` in the language. Like `!Regex.IsMatch()`